# sending multipart/form-data POST API requests in angualr

Tags: angular, forms, api, post, multipart

I'm sending images and other form data through multi-part requests. When I call the api using PostMan the image is successfully adding. But I;m getting an error from back-end when I call the same API using angular code.

[image]

***Component.ts***

```
addOffer() {
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.formData.append('promotion', this.file, this.file.name);
    this.formData.append("main_text", this.offerAddForm.controls['title'].value);
    this.formData.append("type", '1');
    this.formData.append("footer_text", 'rdy');

    this._addOfferService.addOffer(this.formData)
      .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log("Yo yo "+data);
            },
            error => {
              console.log("An Error Occurred add notify ", error);
            });
  }
```

***Service.ts***

```
addOffer(formData) {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    });

    const url = environment.baseURL + 'promotions';
    return this.http.post<any>(url, formData, {headers: headerOptions})
      .pipe(map(response => {
        return response;
      }));
  }
```

Update:
***Error From back-end:***

An invalid promotion type.

***Request Payload :***

[image]

[image]

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @R.Richards Please see the updated section.

Comment: Do you see an error in the console? If so, what does it show?

Comment: @R.Richards Please see the last image I have uploaded to question. It's 400: Bad Request

Comment: The error also says *Invalid promotion type*. So, whatever you're sending, the API doesn't like it. 400 errors mean your not sending the API what it needs. Make sure what you're posting is what the API expects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('cc', this.PayElement.CC);

    // alert(urlSearchParams.toString());
    this.appService.sendToOtherService('https://dddddd?ggg=dfdf&ddgg=5555, 
      urlSearchParams.toString()).then(res2 => {
//

    }).catch(res3 => {
     //
    });



sendToOtherService(url: string, data: any): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(url, data, options).toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as any)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: What did you mean my CC ?

Comment: string to params

Answer (score 0):

In Html

```
    <div>
    <input hidden id="input-file-id" (change)="sendFile($event)" type="file" />
<label for="input-file-id" class="btn btn-warning ">
<img class="mr-3" src="assets/images/choose_file.png" alt="cloud"> Choose
                                        Files</label>
<p style="color: tomato;">{{isErr}}</p>
<div class="row col-md-12 mt-3 ml-0 pt-4 pb-4" style="border: 2px solid #fbbc04">
<div class="col-md-9" id="wrap">
<span>{{ fileName }}</span>
<audio id="buzzer" controls>
<source [src]="audioSrc" id="wav_src" type="audio/wav" />
<source [src]="audioSrc" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

In controller/component

```
sendFile(event) {

this.isErr='';
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
if (fileList.length > 0) {
  let file: File = fileList[0];
  console.log(file);
  console.log(file.name);
  this.fileName = file.name;
  this.fileSize = file.size;
  this.audioSrc = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  $("#buzzer").attr("src", this.audioSrc);
  this.yourServiceObj.sendAudioService(file)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.serviceResponse = data;
    },
      error => {
        this.isErr='Something went wrong! Please try after sometime';
      });
}
}
```

In Service

```
sendAudioService(blob) {
this.apiUrl = 'your api url';
var data = new FormData();
data.append("audio", blob);

return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data, {responseType: 'text'})
  .pipe(map(response => {
    return response;
  }));
}
```

Comment: @Lalinda Sampath, I think you are not sending "this.file"  correctly. You have not specified from where you are getting it.